# Couchbase object of objects query

Tags: database, couchbase, sql++, nosql

In our couchbase db, we have a bucket with relatively large objects. These objects have other objects inside let's say *people*. This should be an array, however for some reason we had to create it as an object of objects, and this is how it looks like:

```
{
    "companyName": "company name",
    "companyid": "11111-GUID-11111",
    "people": {
        "22222-GUID-22222": {
            "peopleid": "22222-GUID-22222",
            "name": "name1"
        },
        "33333-GUID-33333": {
            "peopleid": "33333-GUID-33333",
            "name": "name2"
        },
        "44444-GUID-44444": {
            "peopleid": "44444-GUID-44444",
            "name": "name3"
        }
    }
}
```

It also have sub-objects with similar structure.

My question is, how can I make a query which could respond with all the "company" objects which has people in it with the name *"name1"* (for example).

As I said people objects also have sub-objects, let's say *pets*, with ids. Can I make a query which can search that deep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT d.* FROM default AS d WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(d.people) SATISFIES v.name = "name1" END;

OR

SELECT d.* FROM default AS d WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_PAIRS(d.people) SATISFIES v.`val`.name = "name1" END;

Comment: Tested this and it's working correctly, thank you very much! Before I upvote and accept your answer, could you tell me how could I make a similar query, which only responds with the companies which has people with pets with name "name1"?

Comment: I have found a way: `SELECT d.*
FROM default d
WHERE ANY p IN OBJECT_VALUES(d.people) SATISFIES ANY pet in OBJECT_VALUES(p.pets) SATISFIES pet.name = "name1" END END;` . Thank you again.

Comment: If need to match any object name  (any level) you can use WITHIN. SELECT d.* FROM default AS d WHERE ANY v WITHIN d.people SATISFIES v.name = "name1" END;

Comment: this is also very useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, @vsr. Is there any solution to get back only the matched pet? Actually I'm more interested in the matched people object. Without getting back the companies. Thanks again